Auto-renew - Manage Option and Credit Card Info
I am using CiviCRM with WordPress.  Our site is currently using fixed memberships that last 1 year.  I would like to turn on the option for members to choose auto-renew for the next cycle of membership signups and renew.  The two questions I have are:

Is there anyway (even programmatically) I can allow members to change their auto-renew response (on or off) at any point after they have signed up / renewed?  For example, I have a page where they can update some basic info about themselves and manage groups they are assigned to.  Could I also have an option for them to turn on auto-renew of their membership or does it have to be at the point of sign up/renew when their credit card info is captured?

Is there any way the member can update their credit card info before the next auto-renew cycle?  Because the membership is for 1 year it is not uncommon for someone's credit card to expire before the next time their membership needs to auto-renew.  Authorize.net is the payment processor.  Is there a link or something that is autogenerated as part of the email reminders that would allow users to update their credit card information through Authorize.net?  I apologize for my ignorance, I am working with a client that manages the Authorize.net side so I am not aware of what happens on that side.  Perhaps Authorize.net manages email communication and information updates about expiring credit cards?


Thank you for your time and help.

do folk have access to their civicrm dashboard? iirc we did a tweak so that via the dashboard they could cancel their auto-renew
